# How to generate different color than last time

Tags: java, android, random

In `colors.xml` I have this `Array`:

```
<item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
<item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
<item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
<item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

<integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
    <item>@color/darkred</item>
</integer-array>
```

I generate random color with,

```
int[] androidColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.androidcolors);
int randomAndroidColor = androidColors[new Random().nextInt(androidColors.length)];
button1.setBackgroundColor(randomAndroidColor);
```

It works good but sometimes it generates the same as last time. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to save last generated color and use "if statements". If oldColor==newColor...

Comment: but i dont know how i can do this

Comment: Show complete code how you generate colors...is it on button click or on activity start....

Comment: @ImadElFetouh please do not add code here. instead update your question with the provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ***don't*** create a `new Random()` every time you want a new color, that's both computationally expensive and utterly destroys the distributional properties of class `Random`!!!  Just create a single `static` instance of `Random` and reuse it.

Now for your actual question.  You'll need to remember the last value you generated so you can avoid repeating it.  Create either a static variable or an instance variable of the class you're working in.  Let's call it `lastColorIndex`, and initialize it to a randomly selected color.

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
static int lastColorIndex = rnd.nextInt(androidColors.length);
```

To generate non-repeating colors, you can now do:

```
int randomColorIndex = rnd.nextInt(androidColors.length - 1);
if (randomColorIndex >= lastColorIndex) {
   ++randomColorIndex;
}
lastColorIndex = randomColorIndex;

button1.setBackgroundColor(androidColors[randomColorIndex]);
```

To generate the `randomColorIndex`, you have one less choice than the number of colors because the last one you used is excluded.  If you generate an index greater than or equal to the last one used, you increment it.  This results in outcomes uniformly distributed over the full range of indices *exclusive of the* `lastColorIndex`.